# How to add a new item to struct in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, arrays

I have a struct in JavaScript

```
    settings = {
        "type-1": {
            "setting-1": true,
            "setting-2": 2
         }
        "type-2": {
            "setting-3": "value",
         }
    };
```

I can modify the items:

```
settings["type-1"]["setting-1"] = false;
```

But how can I add a new item in this struct?

Trying

```
settings["type-new"]["setting-100"] = "new one";
```

But settings["type-new"] is undefined. So how to add a new one?

Comment: Note that the term "struct" doesn't apply in JavaScript. You are using an "object literal" (also sometimes called an "object initialiser") to define an "object", and you then modify properties of the object. (In your example with the nested object literals you actually create three objects.)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to set settings["type-new"] to an object first.

```
settings["type-new"] = {};
settings["type-new"]["setting-100"] = "new one";
```

Comment: Thank you, Dogbert! Sagivo gave a good suggestion too, but I accept your answer since you were first.

Answer (score 4):

you can do it on one line:

```
settings["type-new"] = {"setting-100": "new one"}
```

Answer (score 1):

Dogbert got it right, since you're using object literals (that's what they're called, not structs :P), you have to create them, before you can assign values to them. Doing `settings["type-new"]["setting-100"] = "new one";` is equivalent to `undefined["setting-100"] = "new one";`. That's why it doesn't work.

On the side, you're really better off not using dashes in your keys, I find it easier to write code like yours along the lines of:

```
settings.typeNew.setting100 = "new one";
```

Which is more intuitive (the `[""]` notation is very serviceable in cases where the property name is the value of a variable, and you -rightly so- don't want to use eval).

Comment: I would prefer this method too, but name of items are dynamic, so I can not use this in my case. Thank you for explanation! :)

Comment: In that case, you're right to use `['']`, of course. Happy coding